# Can i use welding cable as primary coil for Tesla coil?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, cables, electricity, tesla-coil

I am trying to make DRSSTC (see NOTE1) and struggle to find copper tube for my Tesla coil, so I'm looking for other stuff that I can use for the primary coil. Now I think, can I use welding cable like **Lincoln Moswell welding cable 35mm** as the primary coil? 
I want to use this cable because its easy to set and avaible on local store near my house.

NOTE1: DRSSTC means double resonant solid state Tesla coil. Here's one example: https://www.loneoceans.com/labs/drsstc2/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the initialisation DRSSTC.

Answer (score 4):

No, because it would have high skin effect loses. Beside this, the copper tube is cheaper than ruining expensive welding cable (high temperature).

You can find a copper tube almost everywhere in a plumber shop. Keep the money, you'll need it for transistors.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say no it won't work. There's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Actually, if the wire is solid, it won't be 98% useless, it is even worse. Using a copper tube with same circumference would give better results, the inner part of solid wire not only it doesn't conduct, rather it "pushes" the current to the surface. So with the same circumference, a hollow tube would perform much better.

Comment: Fair enough. I think we both agree that it's wasteful to use welding cable, but I still don't think we can honestly say it won't work. It probably will, it's just entirely illogical. And yes, performance may suffer slightly, though whether it's noticeable or not is up for debate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why welding cable wouldn't work for a DRSSTC primary. Welders use similar high-current, high-frequency power to DRSSTCs, and being made of copper its conductivity is excellent. That being said, it does seem a bit wasteful to use thick multistranded copper cable when the inside is largely unused due to the skin effect. Assuming a nominal frequency of 100kHz (typical for a small-to-medium sized DRSSTC), the skin depth would be around 0.2mm, meaning that almost 98% of the copper in a 35mm welding cable would be useless. That's a lot of copper to have there for no reason. This is why hollow tubing is generally preferred for DRSSTC primary coils. Welding cable is also very heavy and bulky, so it will take up a lot of unnecessary space. This may affect the coupling to the secondary, if your primary coil has to be so large that the outer windings sit too far away from the secondary, assuming a pancake or conical coil.

You can find copper tubing at just about any hardware store for fairly cheap, depending on how much you need. My small DRSSTC used about 20 feet of 1/4" copper tubing I bought at my local hardware store for a little over $20 USD. Much cheaper than welding cable, and a much more efficient use of material, space, and money.